# DD4T call to broker API Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: dd4t

I have been looking around and it looks like there are a few causes to this. I saw another post that says it is a license issue. I am pretty sure my license file is fine though.

I have installed DD4T and created the items on need on the CM side. I [followed this overview](http://remcorakers.nl/dd4t-development-environment/). However when I load my page I always get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" I have verified my page is published out to my broker database in the page table and verified the publication ID matches what my app has.

I have seen this error in the event log from time to time but it does not corispond to each request I make.

> DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer DEP-DB-CMS-DEV using any of the configured protocols; requested by PID     38c4 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe).

Any ideas on why I can't get this call to work? 
Here are some things I have done:

- Copied the config folder from the HttpUpload deployer to make sure I have right config settings. I made sure to update the license path in the cd_storage config to my local license file path.
- Validated my publication ID
- Validated that my page shows up in the broker DB link to the above publication ID.
- Changing DD4T DefaultPage from "index.aspx" to "/index.aspx" ... database record in the Page table has "/index.aspx"

App exception

> Exception information: 
>       Exception type: NullReferenceException 
>       Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2013.TridionPageProvider.GetContentByUrl(String Url)
>      at DD4T.Factories.PageFactory.TryFindPage(String url, IPage& page)
>      at DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.TridionControllerBase.GetModelForPage(String PageId)
>      at DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.TridionControllerBase.Page(String pageId)
>      at ContentDelivery.Web.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageId

Comment: any other info in event viewer logs?

Comment: nope. those logs seems odd but since they don't show up every time I make a request I am not sure they are the root cause.

Comment: also check your CD logs, log path is in logback.xml

Comment: both logback.xml files on CD HttpUpload and CD site have not been updated (written to) in days. Same with my local logback.xml file.

Comment: Raj can you confirm my setup. Maybe I have done something dumb there. In my local IIS I have created a under the bin folder a lib folder that contains all the jar files and a config file that contains cd_deployer_conf.xml, cd_dynamic_conf.xml, cd_licenses.xml, cd_storage_conf.xml, logback.xml

Comment: an IIS reset seems to have solved it. Maybe it was holding on to a config that had the bad license file in it? Now I get page cannot be found error. I think this is a step forward but not sure why it can't find my Default.cshtml view.

Comment: @ToddB That means it can't find a Tridion Page for the specified path, not that it can't find a view - the view is selected based on the Page Metadata. Compare the path you're entering to the path of the Page in the broker.

Comment: @ToddB An IIS Reset is needed to reflect the config changes.  IIS holds onto the JAR and Config files and doesn't reload them.  Page not found is a great sign!  Look in your Broker Pages Table and at the URL column.  This is your missing link.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure if you have copied "netrtsn.dll" and "xmogrt.dll" in the bin folder. You should be able to get these DLLs from CD bin folder.